# Implementing SIGEV_THREAD in Solaris10.

Tags: c++11, time, solaris-10

As we Know SIGEV_THREAD not supported by Solaris 10, But I need this for my task Scheduler in Solaris 10. So i took the code of **timer_create.c** from google and all other required file also.

so now I am trying to compile my code, given below errow i got:

```
bash-3.2$ g++ -I./ -std=c++11 -o sol10 *.cpp
Undefined                       first referenced
symbol                             in file
__timer_mutex                       /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
_Z20__timer_thread_startP11thread_node /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
_Z13__timer_allocv                  /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
__timer_signal_thread_rclk          /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
__timer_init_failed                 /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
_Z15__timer_deallocP10timer_node    /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
_Z20__timer_thread_allocPK13_pthread_attri /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
_Z17__timer_init_oncev              /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
_Z22__timer_thread_deallocP11thread_node /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
_Z28__timer_thread_find_matchingPK13_pthread_attri /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
__timer_init_once_control           /var/tmp//ccVywNSJ.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to sol10
.
```

I am unable to get this error please help me to figure ut this.
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: *So i took the code of timer_create.c from google and all other required file also.*  Not all required files, apparently.  From the looks of it, you're trying to recreate a significant portion of `glibc`'s threading implementation.  You'd do a lot better recoding your application to not use `SIGEV_THREAD` if you have to run on Solaris 10.  The computing world existed for more than half a century without it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am creating a Task Scheduler in which I want to invoke function as a thread at particular time, and I am not getting any other way to do it.. , If u have any idea please let me know :)

Comment: Hi Andrew, this line touched to me "The computing world existed for more than half a century without it". and very thankyou to you I Implement one logic by which i can do whatever i want :)

Thnaks Andrew :)